# Coffeescript - reassign upper-scope variable using a function

Tags: coffeescript

```
fun=->
    views = []
views = 123
fun()
console.log views
```

Which compiles to

```
  var fun, views;
  fun = function() {
    var views;
    return views = [];
  };
  views = 123;
  fun();
  console.log(views);
```

And logs `123` whereas I want it to return `[]`.
Declaring `views` *before* `fun` would produce required result, but my code style requires that I first declare all functions and then assign variables.
What can be done in this case? Particularly I want coffeescript to not produce `var views;` in javascript inside `fun`.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility - while a bit more compex - would be to use a class and bind the function and the fun function to the class scope.

```
class muchFun
    views: 123
    fun: =>
        @views = []
        return

soMuchFun = new muchFun()
console.log( soMuchFun.views )
soMuchFun.fun()
console.log( soMuchFun.views )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `fun` to know about the outer `views` then you have to define `views` before `fun`:

```
views = 123
fun = ->
    views = []
```

Comment: That's very inconvenient for some cases =(

Comment: So is everything else. Maybe you should be using a class to keep your functions and variables together rather than attempted scope trickery.